# animate addPlotBand Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to add a plotband that has a smooth transition? Before I am using

> **addPlotLine** and
>   **addPlotBand**

```
chart.yAxis[0].removePlotBand('plot-band-1');
chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-1');

var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);

chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand({
    from: 100000,
    to: y,
    color: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: 1, y2: 0 },
        stops: [
            [0, 'rgba(46, 230, 0, 0.22)'],
            [1, 'rgba(46, 230, 0, 0)'] //down
        ]
    },
    id: 'plot-band-1'
 });

chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
    value: y,
    color: 'red',
    width: 2,
    id: 'plot-line-1'
});
```

to plot the point on a dynamic chart, but now I am using **animate** to make the plotting smoother

```
        plotLine = yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem;
        d = plotLine.d.split(' ');

        newY = yAxis.toPixels(y) - d[2];

        plotLine.animate({
          translateY: newY
        }, 300);
```

Also I am trying the solution from this [Highcharts plotBand animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777698/highcharts-plotband-animation#answer-43783181). however it seems that I am unable to implement it properly.
For your reference **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fahk7L36/)** is the code of where is used addPlotLine and addPlotBand and **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/2mkg2y09/)** is the current code style being used. Appreciate your help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass path d attribute as an array, you can animate it as a simple shape.

Add the plotband before setiInterval and animate it as the plotline on every interval.

```
const plotbandPath = plotband.svgElem.d.split(' ')
plotbandPath[7] = plotbandPath[9] = newY

plotband.svgElem.animate({
  d: plotbandPath
}, 300)
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/sqer2x13/

Comment: this worked! but can i request something @morganfree ? I am trying to do a thing wherein I have a button, and when I hover the button it will display the plotband you did, can you further help me ? appreciate your help :)

Comment: On mouseover you can add/move plotband and on mouseleave you can delete plot band, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pz9230r4/